# How to create custom excerpt?

Tags: wordpress

On the frontend pages, I want to add the date interval field (From and To)
neatly in bold under the excerpt title name.

The `the_excerpt()` method calls the `get_the_excerpt()` method. These methods getting the excerpt from the database. And with `get_the_excerpt` filter, they add the data intervals to the excerpt and show it on the frontend. The date intervals are not in the database. I am a beginner and tried to solve this problem with google but no solution so far.

```
<div class="listing-row-body">
        <h2 class="listing-row-title"><a href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>"><?php echo Inventor_Utilities::excerpt( get_the_title(), 50 ); ?></a></h2>
        <div class="listing-row-content">
            <?php the_excerpt(); ?>

            <p>
                <a class="read-more-link" href="<?php echo esc_attr( get_permalink( get_the_ID() ) ); ?>"><?php echo esc_attr__( 'Read More', 'inventor' ); ?><i class="fa fa-chevron-right"></i></a>
            </p>
        </div><!-- /.listing-row-content -->
    </div><!-- /.listing-row-body -->
```

Comment: I think you have the dates added somewhere else, excerpt don't show dates by default

Comment: You are right, I just can not find where. Do you have any idea?

Comment: I can't without looking at the code that display the HTML elements